# PHP conexión a SQL Server funciona pero no permite hacer queries

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, sql-server-2014

Mi entorno es el siguiente: PHP 7.3 en WSL de Ubuntu 18.04; SQL Server 2014 en un servidor remoto dentro del mismo dominio.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "192.168.42.45, 1433";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "AuraPortal_BPMS", "UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "Sadm2017");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if ($conn) {
        echo "Got a connection!<br />";

        if ($client_info = sqlsrv_client_info($conn)) {
            foreach ($client_info as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
            }
        }

        $server_info = sqlsrv_server_info($conn);
        if ($server_info) {
            foreach ($server_info as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
            }
        } else {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        // Select Query
        $tsql = `SELECT * FROM AP_Dyn_Familias_4 WHERE "3_Nombre Corto" ='APRP-100-03/2019';`;    
        $tsql = "SELECT @@Version AS SQL_VERSION";

        // Executes the query
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);    
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['SQL_VERSION'] . PHP_EOL;
        }    
    } else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

Y me regresa lo siguiente:
[image: result]

Esto es, puedo conectarme a la BD, pero al momento de querer hacer un query normal (como el primer $tsql) se ejecuta, pero regresa vacío o FALSE. El mismo query lo puedo ejecutar remotamente con HeidisQL.
Creo que alguna configuración se me debe estar pasando pero ignoro cuál es. Espero alguien sepa.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Usas mal las comillas en la consulta que dices que no funciona. Prueba así: **`$tsql = "SELECT * FROM AP_Dyn_Familias_4 WHERE 3_Nombre Corto ='APRP-100-03/2019';";`**

Comment: @A.Cedano 3_nombre Corto es el nombre del campo. Esos nombres de campos y tablas, son IMHO, muy malos.

Comment: Claro @gbianchi, y esto también: `AP_Dyn_Familias_4` quizá convenga que el OP se lea algo sobre *convención de nombres* una vez haya resuelto el error.

Comment: Es que el query que le ofreciste no va a andar, por el espacio en el nombre. No se como se interpola un " en una cadena php.. eso tiene que lograr

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, si es sql server, debe usar [] en los nombres de los campos con espacio... su query deberia ser asi: $tsql = "SELECT * FROM AP_Dyn_Familias_4 WHERE [3_Nombre Corto] ='APRP-100-03/2019';";

Comment: @gbianchi deberías poner eso como respuesta

Comment: Los nombres de las tablas y los campos están establecidos por otro sistema que así los usa. No se pueden cambiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En sql server se utilizan los corchetes [] para declarar los nombres de los objetos (campos, tablas).

No son obligatorios si los campos no contienen caracteres como por ejemplo un espacio, pero lo son en casos de que los campos contengan algun caracter especial.

Entonces en tu caso, tu consulta deberia ser:

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM AP_Dyn_Familias_4 WHERE [3_Nombre Corto] ='APRP-100-03/2019';";
```

Comment: Funcionó. Mi problema era que este query
    "SELECT * FROM AP_Dyn_Familias_4 WHERE "3_Nombre Corto" ='APRP-100-03/2019';" así en HeidiSQL si funciona, por lo cual yo interpretaba que no debía tener problema al ponerlo tal cual en PHP. Pero no fue así.